# Thread Deadlocking issue in nLog 4.4.11 When Adding More Than One Async File Targets

Tags: nlog

**Issue Type**: Bug

**Summary**: I am working with a log heavy service that is deadlocking when we add more than one async file targets. I have also noticed the same results when using nLog version 4.5.4

**NLog version**: 4.4.11

**Platform**: .Net 4.5

**Current NLog config**: XML stored in a database

```
<nlog throwExceptions="true" internalLogFile="c:\Temp\nLog.txt">
  <variable name="Empty" value="-" />
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="Company.Diagnostics.ApplicationInsights" />
  </extensions>
  <targets>
    <target type="AsyncWrapper" name="asyncCompanyAi" overflowAction="Grow" timeToSleepBetweenBatches="0" batchSize="1000">
      <target type="CompanyAITarget" name="aiTarget" />
    </target>
    <target type="AsyncWrapper" name="asyncFile" overflowAction="Grow" timeToSleepBetweenBatches="0" batchSize="1000">
      <target name="file" type="File" fileName="${gdc:item=rootPath}\${machinename}.${gdc:item=appName}.log" archiveNumbering="Sequence" archiveAboveSize="10485760" maxArchiveFiles="10" archiveFileName="${gdc:item=rootPath}\Archives\${machinename}.${gdc:item=appName}.{#}.log" autoFlush="True">
        <layout type="LayoutWithHeaderAndFooter">
          <layout type="CsvLayout">
            <column name="Timestamp" layout="${longdate:uppercase=true:whenEmpty=${Empty}}" />
            <column name="Level" layout="${level:uppercase=true:whenEmpty=${Empty}}" />
            <column name="Logger" layout="${logger:whenEmpty=${Empty}}" />
            <column name="ThreadId" layout="${threadid:whenEmpty=${Empty}}" />
            <column name="AppName" layout="${gdc:item=appName:whenEmpty=${Empty}}" />
            <column name="OperationId" layout="${event-properties:item=RequestId:whenEmpty=${Empty}}" />
            <column name="URL" layout="${event-properties:item=URL:whenEmpty=${Empty}}" />
            <column name="DSN" layout="${event-properties:item=DSN:whenEmpty=${Empty}}" />
            <column name="UserId" layout="${event-properties:item=UserId:whenEmpty=${Empty}}" />
            <column name="LoginId" layout="${event-properties:item=LoginId:whenEmpty=${Empty}}" />
            <column name="PageId" layout="${event-properties:item=PageId:whenEmpty=${Empty}}" />
            <column name="Message" layout="${replace-newlines:${message}:whenEmpty=${Empty}}" />
            <column name="Exception" layout="${replace-newlines:${exception:format=ToString}:whenEmpty=${Empty}}" />
          </layout>
          <footer type="SimpleLayout" text="" />
        </layout>
      </target>
    </target>
    <target type="AsyncWrapper" name="qa1" overflowAction="Grow" timeToSleepBetweenBatches="0" batchSize="1000">
      <target name="file_qa1" type="File" fileName="${gdc:item=rootPath}\qa1.${machinename}.${gdc:item=appName}.log" archiveNumbering="Sequence" archiveAboveSize="20971520" maxArchiveFiles="20" archiveFileName="${gdc:item=rootPath}\Archives\qa1.${machinename}.${gdc:item=appName}.{#}.log" autoFlush="True">
        <layout type="LayoutWithHeaderAndFooter">
          <layout type="CsvLayout">
            <column name="Timestamp" layout="${longdate:uppercase=true:whenEmpty=${Empty}}" />
            <column name="Level" layout="${level:uppercase=true:whenEmpty=${Empty}}" />
            <column name="Logger" layout="${logger:whenEmpty=${Empty}}" />
            <column name="ThreadId" layout="${threadid:whenEmpty=${Empty}}" />
            <column name="AppName" layout="${gdc:item=appName:whenEmpty=${Empty}}" />
            <column name="OperationId" layout="${event-properties:item=RequestId:whenEmpty=${Empty}}" />
            <column name="URL" layout="${event-properties:item=URL:whenEmpty=${Empty}}" />
            <column name="DSN" layout="${event-properties:item=DSN:whenEmpty=${Empty}}" />
            <column name="UserId" layout="${event-properties:item=UserId:whenEmpty=${Empty}}" />
            <column name="LoginId" layout="${event-properties:item=LoginId:whenEmpty=${Empty}}" />
            <column name="PageId" layout="${event-properties:item=PageId:whenEmpty=${Empty}}" />
            <column name="Message" layout="${replace-newlines:${message}:whenEmpty=${Empty}}" />
            <column name="Exception" layout="${replace-newlines:${exception:format=ToString}:whenEmpty=${Empty}}" />
          </layout>
          <footer type="SimpleLayout" text="" />
        </layout>
      </target>
    </target>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="asyncFile" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="asyncCompanyAi" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="qa1">
      <filters>
        <when condition="not equals('${uppercase:${event-properties:item=DSN}}', '${uppercase:qaEnv1}')" action="IgnoreFinal" />
        <when condition="not equals('${uppercase:${event-properties:item=LoginId}}', '${uppercase:user1}')" action="IgnoreFinal" />
      </filters>
    </logger>
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

**In case of a BUG: What is the current result?**

- Adding a second async file target results in certain logging heavy services deadlocking

**The following message pulled from the service dump:**

*DEADLOCK DETECTED*
CLR thread 0xb holds the lock on SyncBlock 000000c84538d1f8 OBJ:000000c4fb07dbe8[System.Object]
...and is waiting for the lock on SyncBlock 000000c84538d4c8 OBJ:000000c4fb069e98[System.Object]
CLR thread 0x10 holds the lock on SyncBlock 000000c84538d4c8 OBJ:000000c4fb069e98[System.Object]
...and is waiting for the lock on SyncBlock 000000c84538d1f8 OBJ:000000c4fb07dbe8[System.Object]
CLR Thread 0xb is waiting at NLog.LogFactory.GetLogger(LoggerCacheKey)(+0x5f Native)
CLR Thread 0x10 is waiting at NLog.Targets.Target.NLog.Internal.ISupportsInitialize.Initialize(NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration)(+0x11 IL,+0x45 Native)

**What is the expected result?**

- Adding multiple async targets should not cause a deadlock. (At least I assume it shouldn't)

**Did you checked the [Internal log](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging)?**

- Yes, internal logging is on and has not resulted in an informative error.

**Full exception Details**

**Stack from 1st Thread:**

OS Thread Id: 0x7ec (13)
        Child SP               IP Call Site
000000c84724d5e8 00007fff062c0d0a [GCFrame: 000000c84724d5e8] 
000000c84724d728 00007fff062c0d0a [GCFrame: 000000c84724d728] 
000000c84724d768 00007fff062c0d0a [HelperMethodFrame_1OBJ: 000000c84724d768] System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(System.Object)
000000c84724d860 00007ffe9ca7606f NLog.LogFactory.GetLogger(LoggerCacheKey)
000000c84724d910 00007ffe9ca75ff0 NLog.LogFactory.GetLogger(System.String)
000000c84724d960 00007ffe9ca75f47 Company.Practices.Logging.NLogLogger+c__DisplayClass5.b__4(System.String)
000000c84724d9a0 00007ffefaac1774 System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib],[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].GetOrAdd(System.__Canon, System.Func`2) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\Collections\Concurrent\ConcurrentDictionary.cs @ 1041]
000000c84724da00 00007ffe9ca75e90 Company.Practices.Logging.NLogLogger.GetLogger(System.String)
000000c84724da80 00007ffe9ca75d66 Company.Practices.Logging.NLogLogger.ShouldLog(Company.Practices.Logging.TraceLevel, System.String)
000000c84724daf0 00007ffe9ca42eb1 Company.Practices.Logging.TraceLogger.ShouldLog(Company.Practices.Logging.TraceLevel, System.String)
000000c84724db60 00007ffe9ca42dc9 Company.Practices.Logging.TraceLogger.IfShouldLog(Company.Practices.Logging.TraceLevel, System.String, System.Func`1)
000000c84724dbc0 00007ffe9ca42d47 Company.Practices.Logging.TraceLogger.IfShouldLogVerbose(System.String, System.Func`1)
000000c84724dbf0 00007ffe9ca4178b PetaPoco.Database.OnExecutingCommand(System.Data.IDbCommand)
000000c84724dc50 00007ffe9ca414d6 PetaPoco.Database.DoPreExecute(System.Data.IDbCommand)
000000c84724dd10 00007ffe9c6ce2f6 PetaPoco.Database.CreateCommand(System.Data.IDbConnection, System.String, System.Object[])
000000c84724ddd0 00007ffe9c6cd916 PetaPoco.Database+d__22`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].MoveNext()
000000c84724df40 00007ffefaaeda64 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]]..ctor(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\collections\generic\list.cs @ 104]
000000c84724dfb0 00007ffef917a9c6 System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1)
000000c84724dff0 00007ffe9c6ccec1 PetaPoco.Database.Fetch[[System.__Canon, mscorlib],[System.__Canon, mscorlib],[System.__Canon, mscorlib]](System.Func`3, System.String, System.Object[])
000000c84724e0c8 00007ffefbcb1f3c [StubHelperFrame: 000000c84724e0c8] 
000000c84724e120 00007ffe9c6ca4ad Company.Platform.Central.Configuration.DatabaseConfigurationRepository.Get(System.String, System.String, System.Nullable`1, System.String)
000000c84724e200 00007ffe9c6c9e17 Company.Platform.Central.Configuration.DatabaseConfigurationRepository.Get(System.String)
000000c84724e260 00007ffe9c6c96fa Company.Platform.Central.Configuration.DatabaseConfigurationSource.GetSectionData(System.String, Company.Platform.Central.Configuration.ContextInformation)
000000c84724e440 00007ffe9c6c720f Company.Platform.Central.Configuration.DatabaseConfigurationSource.GetSection(System.String, Company.Platform.Central.Configuration.ContextInformation)
000000c84724e630 00007ffe9c6c6684 Company.Platform.Central.Configuration.DatabaseConfigurationSource.GetSection(System.String)
000000c84724e670 00007ffe9c6c65c4 Company.Practices.Configuration.ConfigurationSourceBase.GetSection[System.__Canon, mscorlib]
000000c84724e6e0 00007ffe9c6c64d8 Company.Practices.Configuration.ConfigurationSourceBase.TryGetSection[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]](System.String, System.__Canon ByRef)
000000c84724e760 00007ffe9c6c621e Company.Diagnostics.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsights.get_ConfigurationSection()
000000c84724e7a0 00007ffe9cb90724 Company.Diagnostics.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryLogger.CreateTelementryClient(Company.Common.UserInfo)
000000c84724e7f0 00007ffe9cb8fa55 Company.Diagnostics.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryLogger.TrackTrace(Company.Common.UserInfo, System.String, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts.SeverityLevel, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2)
000000c84724e840 00007ffe9cb8ea99 NLog.Targets.Target.Write(NLog.Common.AsyncLogEventInfo)
000000c84724e880 00007ffe9cb8e94b NLog.Targets.Target.Write(System.Collections.Generic.IList`1)
000000c84724e8e0 00007ffe9cb82564 NLog.Targets.Target.WriteAsyncThreadSafe(System.Collections.Generic.IList`1)
000000c84724e960 00007ffe9cb82286 NLog.Targets.Target.WriteAsyncLogEvents(System.Collections.Generic.IList`1)
000000c84724ea50 00007ffe9cb74522 NLog.Targets.Wrappers.AsyncTargetWrapper.WriteEventsInQueue(Int32, System.String)
000000c84724eac0 00007ffe9cb7425b NLog.Targets.Wrappers.AsyncTargetWrapper.ProcessPendingEvents(System.Object)
000000c84724eb20 00007ffefab04750 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\executioncontext.cs @ 954]
000000c84724ebf0 00007ffefab045e4 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\executioncontext.cs @ 902]
000000c84724ec20 00007ffefab7389a System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback() [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\timer.cs @ 705]
000000c84724ec80 00007ffefab73688 System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire() [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\timer.cs @ 662]
000000c84724ecf0 00007ffefab7f5d7 System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers() [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\timer.cs @ 417]
000000c84724f168 00007ffefbcb5a03 [DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame: 000000c84724f168]

**Stack from 2nd Thread:**

OS Thread Id: 0x868 (18)
        Child SP               IP Call Site
000000c84844bff8 00007fff062c0d0a [GCFrame: 000000c84844bff8] 
000000c84844c138 00007fff062c0d0a [GCFrame: 000000c84844c138] 
000000c84844c178 00007fff062c0d0a [HelperMethodFrame_1OBJ: 000000c84844c178] System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(System.Object)
000000c84844c270 00007ffe9ca711d5 NLog.Targets.Target.NLog.Internal.ISupportsInitialize.Initialize(NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration)
000000c84844c2d0 00007ffe9ca6f01a NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration.InitializeAll()
000000c84844c340 00007ffe9ca58b13 NLog.LogFactory.ReconfigExistingLoggers()
000000c84844c3b0 00007ffe9ca58a39 NLog.LogFactory.set_GlobalThreshold(NLog.LogLevel)
000000c84844c410 00007ffe9ca5720a NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.ParseNLogElement(NLog.Config.NLogXmlElement, System.String, Boolean)
000000c84844c540 00007ffe9ca56b2e NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.ParseTopLevel(NLog.Config.NLogXmlElement, System.String, Boolean)
000000c84844c590 00007ffe9ca56548 NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.Initialize(System.Xml.XmlReader, System.String, Boolean)
000000c84844c5f0 00007ffe9ca55f2a NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration..ctor(System.Xml.XmlReader, System.String)
000000c84844c640 00007ffe9ca52be1 Company.Practices.Logging.NLogLogger.LoadConfig(System.String)
000000c84844c9e0 00007ffe9ca4216c Company.Practices.Logging.TraceLogger.ReloadLoggingSettings()
000000c84844cb40 00007ffe9cb8eff5 Company.Practices.Logging.TraceLogger.b__1(System.Object, System.EventArgs)
000000c84844cda8 00007ffefbcb5a03 [DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame: 000000c84844cda8] 
000000c84844d0e8 00007ffefbcb5a03 [HelperMethodFrame_PROTECTOBJ: 000000c84844d0e8] System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Signature, Boolean)
000000c84844d260 00007ffefaabf8f2 System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Object[]) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\reflection\methodinfo.cs @ 761]
000000c84844d2d0 00007ffefaaeb419 System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(System.Object[]) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\delegate.cs @ 123]
000000c84844d320 00007ffe9cb8efa6 Company.EventRaiser.InvokeDelegate(System.Delegate, System.Object[])
000000c84844d390 00007ffe9c6a046a Company.EventRaiser.UnsafeRaise(System.Delegate, System.Object[])
000000c84844d410 00007ffe9c6a0380 Company.EventRaiser.Raise(System.EventHandler, System.Object, System.EventArgs)
000000c84844d470 00007ffe9c6a0264 Company.Practices.Configuration.ConfigurationSourceManager.set_Current(Company.Practices.Configuration.IConfigurationSource)
000000c84844d4f0 00007ffe9cb8e348 Company.Platform.Central.Services.CompanyMarketingService`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]]..ctor(System.String, System.Type)
000000c84844d788 00007ffefbcb5a03 [DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame: 000000c84844d788] 
000000c84844dac8 00007ffefbcb5a03 [HelperMethodFrame_PROTECTOBJ: 000000c84844dac8] System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Signature, Boolean)
000000c84844dc40 00007ffefaada68f System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\reflection\ConstructorInfo.cs @ 753]
000000c84844dcc0 00007ffefaaf678f System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo, System.Object[], System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\rttype.cs @ 5279]
000000c84844dd70 00007ffefaaf627a System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo, System.Object[]) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\activator.cs @ 107]
000000c84844ddf0 00007ffefb36d845 System.Activator.CreateInstanceFromInternal(System.String, System.String, Boolean, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo, System.Object[], System.Security.Policy.Evidence) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\activator.cs @ 441]
000000c84844de40 00007ffefb332276 System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(System.String, System.String, Boolean, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo, System.Object[]) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\appdomain.cs @ 4655]
000000c84844dea0 00007ffe9cb8dcbf Company.Reflection.TypeConstructor.CreateInstance(System.AppDomain)
000000c84844df60 00007ffe9cb8db6b Company.Reflection.TypeConstructor.CreateInstance[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]](System.AppDomain)
000000c84844dfd0 00007ffe9cb8cfb4 Company.Services.Subservices.SubserviceController.LoadSubservice()
000000c84844e130 00007ffe9cb8bd10 Company.Services.ServiceRunnerInstance+c__DisplayClassd.b__5(Company.Services.Subservices.SubserviceController)
000000c84844e2b0 00007ffefb4dafec System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel+c__DisplayClass17_0`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].b__1() [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\Tasks\Parallel.cs @ 1193]
000000c84844e370 00007ffefb4ca260 System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(System.Threading.Tasks.Task) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\Tasks\Task.cs @ 2899]
000000c84844e3a0 00007ffefb598f72 System.Threading.Tasks.Task+c__DisplayClass176_0.b__0(System.Object) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\Tasks\Task.cs @ 2624]
000000c84844e410 00007ffefab04750 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\executioncontext.cs @ 954]
000000c84844e4e0 00007ffefab045e4 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\executioncontext.cs @ 902]
000000c84844e510 00007ffefab2c928 System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\Tasks\Task.cs @ 2827]
000000c84844e5c0 00007ffefab2c063 System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\Tasks\Task.cs @ 2767]
000000c84844e600 00007ffefab30463 System.Threading.Tasks.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.TryExecuteTaskInline(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, Boolean) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\Tasks\ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.cs @ 92]
000000c84844e650 00007ffefab3033b System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.TryRunInline(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, Boolean) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\Tasks\TaskScheduler.cs @ 219]
000000c84844e6f0 00007ffefb4c94a7 System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InternalRunSynchronously(System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler, Boolean) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\Tasks\Task.cs @ 1219]
000000c84844e780 00007ffefb4d6592 System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]](Int32, Int32, System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelOptions, System.Action`1, System.Action`2, System.Func`4, System.Func`1, System.Action`1) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\Tasks\Parallel.cs @ 1264]
000000c84844e860 00007ffefb4d78df System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[[System.__Canon, mscorlib],[System.__Canon, mscorlib]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1, System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelOptions, System.Action`1, System.Action`2, System.Action`3, System.Func`4, System.Func`5, System.Func`1, System.Action`1) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\Tasks\Parallel.cs @ 2251]
000000c84844e920 00007ffefb4d70fe System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1, System.Action`1) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\Tasks\Parallel.cs @ 1674]
000000c84844e9c0 00007ffe9cb8190c Company.Services.ServiceRunnerInstance.StartSubservices()
000000c84844ea90 00007ffefab2c686 System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\Tasks\Task.cs @ 2498]
000000c84844ead0 00007ffefab04750 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\executioncontext.cs @ 954]
000000c84844eba0 00007ffefab045e4 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\executioncontext.cs @ 902]
000000c84844ebd0 00007ffefab2c928 System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\Tasks\Task.cs @ 2827]
000000c84844ec80 00007ffefab2c063 System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\Tasks\Task.cs @ 2767]
000000c84844ecc0 00007ffefab0f74e System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\threadpool.cs @ 820]
000000c84844f158 00007ffefbcb5a03 [DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame: 000000c84844f158]

**Are there any workarounds?**

- Currently yes, the workaround is to run as few targets as possible.

**Is there a version in which it did work? **

- No, I have attempted to test with the latest nLog version and I am still seeing the issue with that version.

**Can you help us by writing an unit test?**

- Absolutely, if you can point me in the right direction after a fix is known. Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is the async FileTargets. I think the problem is your own custom target:

```
<target type="AsyncWrapper" name="asyncCompanyAi" overflowAction="Grow" timeToSleepBetweenBatches="0" batchSize="1000">
  <target type="CompanyAITarget" name="aiTarget" />
</target>
```

It seems you are breaking the unwritten rules of NLog, by using NLog-Logger in the custom target:

```
NLog.LogFactory.GetLogger(System.String)
Company.Practices.Logging.NLogLogger.GetLogger(System.String) 
Company.Practices.Logging.TraceLogger.IfShouldLogVerbose(System.String, System.Func1) 
PetaPoco.Database.OnExecutingCommand(System.Data.IDbCommand) 000000c84724dc50 
PetaPoco.Database.CreateCommand(System.Data.IDbConnection, System.String, System.Object[]) 
Company.Platform.Central.Configuration.DatabaseConfigurationRepository.Get(System.String) 000000c84724e260 00007ffe9c6c96fa 
Company.Diagnostics.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryLogger.CreateTelementryClient(Company.Common.UserInfo) 000000c84724e7f0 00007ffe9cb8fa55 
Company.Diagnostics.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryLogger.TrackTrace(Company.Common.UserInfo, System.String, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts.SeverityLevel, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2)
NLog.Targets.Target.WriteAsyncThreadSafe(System.Collections.Generic.IList1)
```

You should only be using the NLog.Common.InternalLogger in custom targets.

P.S. You should also investigate why you are making this call:

```
Company.Practices.Logging.TraceLogger.ReloadLoggingSettings()
```

As reloading the entire NLog configuration while running has a huge overhead.

Comment: This has been working since 2016, but now that we are expanding logging to also output to telemetry in Azure we are seeing issues. We had originally thought the additional file targets were the issue, but you mentioned the Ai target (Application Insights on Azure) could be the issue. This confuses me a little because NLogLogger is one of our classes. I'm currently looking into the ReloadLoggingSettings call and will let you know once I have discovered the reason for calling it. Thank you for the response.